# How to debug and fix random blue screens, in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bsod

My Windows 10 laptop gets a blue screen roughly every other day or so. The reasons tend to vary, the latest one had a `Stop Code: Driver Irql Not Less Or Equal` with `dxgmms2.sys` failing, but this changes around to atleast 2-3 different stop codes.

The typical answer here is Safe mode or update drivers, however since it is random, it is hard to know for sure if any step taken like that is actually fixing. Is it possible to debug it to nail down the culprit so that I can fix it in a more targetted approach?

My computer is a Laptop from 2014, a local builder, likely uses less common components. It is a gaming designed laptop with couple sticks of ram. And Ive pretty much been upgrading in place without wiping it since 2014. I dont really have any other issues other than this blue screen. Ive upgraded it by adding an SSD, but I think the problem might have persisted from before.

Comment: So is this problem with the laptop or the gaming machine?

Comment: What are the other stopcodes and faulting modules? `dxgmms2.sys` is graphics related, are all the others similarly related?

Comment: @Ramhound This laptop IS a gaming oriented laptop which is what i meant.

Comment: @Mokubai I cant recall the other modules, I believe 50-70 percent of the time I dont see a module mentioned. As to the stop code, IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL is quite common ( without the driver_ prefix). I will try to update here with the new BSODS

Comment: Is there any logging I can look for after a BSOD (Or any logging to enable before the BSOD) to get more information?

Comment: [How to Read Memory Dump Files in Windows 10](https://troubleshooter.xyz/wiki/how-to-read-memory-dump-files-in-windows-10/)

Comment: Just had 3 while on Zoom and sharing a game. one was `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL `, missed the 2nd one, and the third had my PC freeze like it was gonna do a BSOD, but just stayed frozen until I hard reset it.

Comment: @Mokubai Nice, Ill also add [How to configure Win10 to create dumps](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5560-configure-windows-10-create-minidump-bsod.html). I currently dont see a minidump or memory.dmp, possibly cuz i didnt have a paging file set for my C drive, have enabled both, ill report back after my next BSOD

Comment: Latest was `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` caused in/by `ntoskrnl.exe` according BlueScreenView

Comment: And another identical case, even the address shown in bluescreenview is the same.

Comment: For now i found devices that are showing a yellow indicator (out of date? ) in device manager, and updated/disabled/uninstalled them. Let me observe if it helps

Comment: Had a `KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED` just now, also pointing at the kernel

Comment: 2 total `KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED` both pointing at `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` in their first parameter as per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x1e--kmode-exception-not-handled

Comment: @Mokubai given this question is asking for diagnostic tools, do you want to add a answer with your link?